# UI Bootstrap typeahead sorting

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using the excellent 'typeahead' control from angular-ui-bootstrap (http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead). My HTML looks like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected"
           typeahead="location.name for location in cities
           | filter:$viewValue  
           | limitTo:8" class="form-control"
           placeholder="City" ng-model="citysearch">
```

My problem is how alternatives are sorted. I would like alternatives starting with the typed text to appear on top, but instead other alternatives which merely *contain* the typed text (sometimes) appear first. For example, consider the following available cities.

New York
London
Los Angeles
Washington
Stockholm

If I type 'S' I would expect Stockholm to appear first, but instead Los Angeles And Washington are first. (Probably because they come before Stockholm in the original array.)

Can I somehow configure this behavior in the typeahead control?

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: You would need to create a custom filter function, see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter#!)